# Use of 'this' in an event

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, this, audio

I need to retrieve some property of an element that trigger the event in this context:

```
 SoundEffect alarm;
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Pad1.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(makeasound);
        Pad2.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(makeasound);
        Pad3.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(makeasound);

     }
```

Pad1,2 and 3 are the names of some Ellipse I have in my xaml. Now if I try to do this in the code executed by the event ( declared immediately after the sample code above):

```
private void makeasound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = this.Name;
        textBlock1.Text = text;
    }
```

The Text Block becomes empty, so I guess the Name of the triggering element never gets there.

Now, things get more messy if I'm trying to retrieve a custom property of the "pads" called "Son", declared with the dependency method , which is a string, like this:

```
private void makeasound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = this.Son;
            textBlock1.Text = text;
        }
```

VS reports error:

'PhoneApplication.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'Son' and no extension method 'Son' accepting a first argument of type 'PhoneApplication.MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Where Phoneapplication is the name of the app and the main namespace of the code behind.
As if it weren't simple enough, what I'm tryin to do is this:

The custom property is actually an INT. I know I declared the dependency right since VS let me compile. Each Pad has this custom property storing an int, and I need to retrieve it to access an array element. The function triggered is this:

```
private void makeasound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = this.Son;
        var sons = new[] { "sons/firstsound.wav", "sons/secondsound.wav", "sons/thirdsound.wav" };
        string target = sons[x];
        StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(
        new Uri(target, UriKind.Relative));
        alarm = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        alarm.Play();
    }
```

So, I declare an array storing URI's for sounds that I'd like to play("son" means sound in french, I'm from Belgium). I then use the INT associated with the triggering element to access the URI of a sound, then I play this sound.

The reason I do this is because I'd like to let the user change the INT value for each pad and therefore choose what sound each pad plays. The fact that I seem to have no choice but to declare this array each time the function is called (otherwise it's not in context) is not very elegant but I guess I can live with that ( array will have 50-60 elements in it)

So, for those who read this far, my problem is to use a property of the triggering event, which seems to be harder when it's a custom property. I put the rest of the logic in case someone had advices.

I thank anyone who read this message and who could maybe help me sorting this out. I read online documentation and I have two good c# books, but I havent found a solution for me.
Have a nice day.

**EDIT:** Some others are willing to help so here is the declaration of the dependency property(Sorry Daniel, hadn't seen you commented my original post)

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    public static class MyClass
    {


        public static readonly DependencyProperty SonProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Son",
            typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static string GetSon(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            return (string)element.GetValue(SonProperty);
        }
        public static void SetSon(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            element.SetValue(SonProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

`Mynamespace` is nested inside the main namespace.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `Son` and how you set its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the current instance of `MainPage`. Not to the pad that was clicked. That's the `sender`:

```
var pad = (Pad)sender;
var text = pad.Name;
textBlock1.Text = text;
```

`Son` is an attached property, not a normal one. You can get its value like this:

```
var pad = (Pad)sender;
var son = MyClass.GetSon(pad);
```

Please note that you have declared it as a `string`. Seeing how you want to use it, it seems to make more sense to declare it as an `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, because this isn't mentionned in either of the two books I have. What you wrote works, but would you know why it doesn't work with custom properties? I still have the error message mentionned just after the third sample code of my original post...Thank you, anyway

Comment: Thanks! I'm almost there...please bear with me one more second and I put the "Green check" on the left! VS says that the name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context. Structure is this: immediately after the function we're talking about comes the closing curly brace that ends the -public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage-.After that is a new namespace called -MyNamespace- and then the 'MyClass' we're talking about. So MyClass belongs to MyNamespace that is nested inside the main namespace. Thank you have getting me this far

Comment: @user2062760: You need to make sure to add the correct `using` at the top of your file. Something like `using MyNamespace;` or `using MainNamespace.MyNamespace;`

Comment: AND IT WORKS!!! I haven't explored the site in depth, but if there's a way to send you a couple euros, I'll gladly do it...You spent some time on it, several times. The fact that guys help unknow guys makes me fell like it's a cool world. Thanks again, because I don't know programmers in the real world and my problem was too specific to find a solution in a book. Yes!Cheers from Belgium!

Comment: Eric Philippe and user2062760 are me... I just changed my displayed name

Comment: @EricPhilippe: Glad it worked out for you! No need to send money, on this site, although optional, you show your gratitute by accepting and upvoting answers. BTW: I think every introductary C# book explains `this`, namespaces and how to use them. Maybe you want to re-read your books. And make sure it's a book on C#, not WPF.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the instance of the type in which the method is defined in, in this case, `MainPage`.  If you want to get the instance of the type that triggered the event, that's what's in the `sender` parameter:

```
private void makeasound(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Text = ((Pad)sender).Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, as mentionned above, but not with a custom property created with the "dependency method". Still have the error mentionned.

Comment: @user2062760 Then you're not casting it to the proper type.  We don't know what that type is.

Comment: The Custom property is called "Son" and is string type. If I take the code suggested above by Daniel Higarth and replace "Name" by "Son", I got the error message and the program doesn't compile...the dependency is declared inside a class that belongs to a namespace nested inside the main namespace. Maybe I don't understand what you say by 'casting it to the proper type'. If so, please tell me. Thanks anyway

Comment: What is the type that defines the `Son` property?